# MySQL outputting help/options when executing from command line

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following query from the command line in Raspbian:

```
mysql -u $NAME -p $PASS Tweets -e "SELECT count(*) FROM raw_tweets;"
```

And it is outputting the following. I'm sure it's a setting somewhere, but all of my searching has been fruitless. Thanks in advance for the help.

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (armv7l) using readline 6.2
>   Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
>   owners.

```
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                  --disable-auto-rehash.
                  (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
  -A, --no-auto-rehash 
                  No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                  table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                  mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
  --auto-vertical-output 
                  Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
                  result is wider than the terminal width.
  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
                  (Enables --silent.)
  --character-sets-dir=name 
                  Directory for character set files.
  --column-type-info  Display column type information.
  -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
                  default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
                  with --comments.
  -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.
  -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  --debug-check       Check memory and open file usage at exit.
  -T, --debug-info    Print some debug info at exit.
 ....... (Abbreviated, above should give enough of an example)
```

Comment: Are these variables `$NAME` and `$PASS` defined somehere? Are you using linux or windows?

Comment: Does your query even execute?

Comment: The actual username and password are in there, just omitted them, and it doesn't appear that the query is executing here. however, when I launch MySQL and run it from there, they query does execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is almost right, you forgot the add the database name parameter. Try this:

```
mysql -u $NAME -p $PASS -e "SELECT count(*) FROM raw_tweets" yourDBname
```

If `Tweets` is your database name, try this:

```
mysql -u $NAME -p $PASS -e "SELECT count(*) FROM raw_tweets" Tweets
```

Where `$NAME` and `$PASS` is your username and password with grants both for the database and the table.

No need of the semicolon. If you are running just one select command.

Comment: Unfortunately, this yielded the same output. Other syntax I researched included the DB name before the statement to be executed, and it seems moving it has no impact

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (armv7l) using readline 6.2

Comment: :) Glad that it helped